# How to find exe name from process id

Tags: api, vb6

I have a function that ends process of active window. it gets window handle then finds its process id and ends its process. but the problem is (explorer.exe)

I want to put a condition to ignore end process if the process name is equal to (explorer.exe)

But i don't know how

This is my code:

```
Private Sub ENDS_WINDOW_PROCESS(Window_Handle As Long)

    Dim target_process_id As Long
    Dim target_process_handle As Long

    If Window_Handle = 0 Then
        'MsgBox "Error finding target window handle"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    GetWindowThreadProcessId Window_Handle, target_process_id
    If target_process_id = 0 Then
        'MsgBox "Error finding target process ID"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    target_process_handle = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE Or PROCESS_TERMINATE, ByVal 0&, target_process_id)

    If target_process_handle = 0 Then
        'MsgBox "Error finding target process handle"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If TerminateProcess(target_process_handle, 0&) = 0 Then
        'MsgBox "Error terminating process"
    Else
        'MsgBox "Process terminated"
    End If

    CloseHandle target_process_handle
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this function (modification from http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?763427-RESOLVED-Get-exe-name-from-Process-ID-fails-Help)

```
Public Function GetExeName(pid As Long) As String
    Dim Process As Object
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim lPos As Long
    On Error GoTo GetFileErr:

    'Scan process and find pid then return the path and exe name
    For Each Process In GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")
        If (pid = CLng(Process.ProcessID)) Then
            'Return exe path
            sFilePath = Process.ExecutablePath
            lPos = InStrRev(sFilePath, "\", Compare:=vbTextCompare)
            If lPos > 0 Then GetExeName = Mid$(sFilePath, lPos + 1)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next Process

    Exit Function

GetFileErr:
    GetExeName = vbNullString
End Function
```

Comment: also, i have posted this question in vbforums.com and i think the answer was better than yours... the link is here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?882939-How-to-find-exe-name-from-process-id anyway both of them works well :)

Comment: @MahdiJazini They are doing the same thing. WMI is an easy way to access system information. It uses the techniques shown at your link (there is only one underlying way to access system information). Therefore they are technically equivalent. They are both using the _Process Status Helper_ API.